# Do I have to I have to run dynamic website with node server when I dont use ssr?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I wonder if I don't use server side rendering in next.js, do I have to I have to run dynamic website with node server? I mean, nextjs doesn't create an index.html file like react. Therefore, I can't run the project without node server. I hope I could express the situation

Comment: If you don't use SSR you don't need next.js, just plain react. It seems like a plain web server will do.

Comment: If you're not using SSR and don't want to run a node server, but still want to stick with Next.js, you have the option to do a [static HTML export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export). The `index.html` file will be in the `out` directory.

Comment: you can use `next export` command to generate HTML outputs if you are not using server side features

Comment: Thank you your answers, I want to make dynamic website, so it is not beneficial using next export command. My conclusion from your comments is I have to use a node server for the frontend to create a dynamic website with nextjs even if the backend uses a separate web server. Am I wrong?

Comment: @salytem I think you'll need to clarify what you mean by "dynamic." If you mean to say "interactive" (e.g., a single page application), then `next export` is still a good option. The node server in this situation is only needed to pre-render the HTML files during development (`next build/export`). When those exported pages are loaded by the browser, they'll still be interactive because of [hydration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydration_(web_development)). So your website is still "dynamic" without a node server (and you're now free to use a different server, if necessary).

Comment: @MarkG By dynamic, I mean a web page that can receive new data using db or api after the page is loaded. I guess if I use static html export I can't use nextjs Api Route or getSeverSideProps etc. I think I can't use "next export" for a blog page with new posts constantly being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still have a dynamic website even without the Node.js server (i.e., static HTML export). You'll need to use [client-side data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side):

> Client-side data fetching is useful when your page doesn't require SEO indexing, when you don't need to pre-render your data, or when the content of your pages needs to update frequently. Unlike the server-side rendering APIs, you can use client-side data fetching at the component level.

A Node.js server will be required if you want to use Next's own API routes in the same project or if you change your mind and want to use SSR features (e.g., `getSeverSideProps`) afterall. In my own experience, for example, I've paired a static generated frontend from Next (served by Caddy) with a REST API written in Go and had no issues fetching new data from a Postgres DB.